# Android: soft keyboard stays visible on return from Gmail activity on Xoom

Tags: android

As the title says. I have tried the usual,

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(root.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

in `OnResume()`, but it does not work, presumably because the keyboard is open from the Gmail window, not my app's window.

Stepping through the code shows `imm.mActive` == false at this point, if that matters. I tried putting this code in `OnPostResume()`, but still no effect.

I have tried using `InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS` instead of `0`, but also no effect.

The built-in gallery app does not have this problem, so I think a solution is possible.

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need get the applications context in order to hide the keyboard. Something like this:

```
View v = (Your Base Layout) findViewById(R.id....);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

If that doesn't work you can also try this:

```
this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm a "beginnger" with Android, but I feel this has something to do with the application's context. I looked through the API for android.content.Context, taking into consideration what u said about the same problem not happening when switching from the gallery app, and I thought maybe this has something to do with the Gmail app not killed completely when switching apps. There's a method called `this.getApplicationContext.stopService(Intent intent)` which you could use to finish killing the Gmail app from your onResume() method. I dont have a Xoom to try this out on so I can't test b4 I suggest

Comment: Still no luck. I even used the same Intent that launched it. The `stopService()` function returned false, indicating that it could not find the Service. Maybe the Gmail app is not considered a Service.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make sure my EditText no longer had focus before navigating to the Gmail activity:

```
contactSearchView.clearFocus()
```